# What can be done to replicate the look of Andrew Bayda photographs?

Tags: post-processing, reverse-engineering, contrast

Look please [photos](http://andrewbayda.com/) of Andrew Bayda. Can tell me anybody please how does he reach so poppy color and cotrast?

I think one of secrets is using Capture One Pro soft, but I'm using that software too long, and I really cant repeat quality of his post-process.

Please help me!

Comment: Can you provide a link to an example you've tried and don't like it?

Comment: http://cs11307.userapi.com/v11307922/84c/KduUc4-hk3s.jpg for example.

Comment: Looks like a form of HDR to me.

Comment: Many photographers are fairly open about their work process, have you tried just asking?

Comment: It's nothing to do with using Capture One, I'm fairly sure. I would think there's some Photoshop involved somewhere. I like your example personally. I'd agree with rfusca; e-mail the guy and ask him, it can't hurt.

Comment: i did :) his answer is "i`m using a "make perferct" button" :) 
about PS.. he is nightclub photographer, and he has many many photos from nightclubs and all of them are looks like each other. I think this packet post processing could take a lot of time if he was processing every photo separately.. So i think there is a way about plugins, special preferences, may be  even color space, i dont know.. :(
about Capture One - his idol is Nick Onken (btw, my too), and he is using only capture one software, because of using another algorithm of processing photo than adobe products, and i like it too)

Comment: sorry, nick onken  using Capture One for initial editing, like exposure, wb, contrast.. and then  copletely finish his work in PS)

Comment: http://cs301205.userapi.com/v301205460/1771/Ioevmzhi5JY.jpg this one for example also) contrast, very smooth and poppy colors.. i'm going be mad while solving this puzzle :(

Comment: Well, regarding his club work - realize, even in the club, this guy is carrying around a non-trivial sized light.  Take a look at some of the catchlights. http://andrewbayda.com/club_life/photo/5  Many times on these kinds of work, the lighting plays a big part.

Comment: @rfusca is right, these are the result of some excellent work with the camera -- they don't rely exclusively on available light. It's even more complicated because the lights have to be balanced with the ambient light to allow for the depth in the images. If you really believe that C1 is his magic tool, Phase One offers a free 60-day demo and you can find out for yourself. Know in advance that Capture One is a nontrivial piece of software and will take some time to learn. However, many pros like it and use it (many use Lightroom or Bridge for that matter).

Comment: Some photographers don't actually do their lightroom work (shootist only), so he might not even know, and color and contrast (scene) matching is typically something done by a colorist in video. I agree the lighting itself is very important, and I still think there's some HDR type of effect being used. Look at [Magic Bullet](http://www.redgiantsoftware.com/products/all/magic-bullet-suite/), for instance (what was The Orphanage), their PS plugins can also do similar things with recipes. Just remember you can't enhance what's not in the original.

Comment: Thank you guys! About extra light - i like photos from USA trip, NY especially, and i dont think he is using some extra light there :) However, i thrust that getting the right original image is almost all secret!
Btw, thanks for  Magic Bullet, will check out =) can i use this one with PS or only AE\AP soft?

Comment: just finished triyng Magic Bullet PhotoLooks... its definetely not a such result, i cant even find any HDR-like filter or smth else)
is there any other components for PS from Magic Bullet packet? i cant find any one which is working with PS except photlooks :(

Comment: By the way, i do agree that there is some hdr effect.. :) a little bit, but a very strange result, not usual :( 
UPD: http://500px.com/Andrew_Bayda check this link also... :( 
there are many superb photos where you can check his post process.

Comment: wow. i was not aware of this work. thanks for posting about this! i'd also love to learn how to get my photos one step closer to this sort of contrast and clartity

Comment: you are welcome, but.. i think i wont get the answer ever :(

Answer (score 4):

Just based on the frontpage you linked I have the following remarks:

**light conditions on the field**

All pictures, except for the B&W versions, are taken in bright sunlight. Almost no clouds on all these pictures. This is the available light on the field.

Bright sunlight gives harsh shadows and high contrast pictures. This definetely is the first step.

**subject**

colorful subjects. Red, green, blue and yellow, all primary colors are seen in these pictures. Choose subjects with these brights colors. Thanks to the direct sunlight these colors are even brighter.

**post processing**

For post processing it's not really what tool he uses that is important. It's rather the technique you have to look for. Start by capturing your images in RAW format.

In some cases he seems to be using HDR and a very soft approach of the Dave Hill effect. Also search high pass filter tutorials.